# OAuth-server, storing user tokens

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

There is a problem to realize my OAyuth-2 server.
Can I store the Access-tokens of users on the server? If not, how can I make it so that each user would have had only one working Access-token? I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question sounds strange. It is the role of an OAuth server to generate and manage access tokens. "***Can I*** store access tokens?". Well, instead, "***You must*** store access tokens."